# What is gevent.queue.Channel?

Tags: python, queue, gevent, channel

Under Gevent's [what's new](http://gevent.org/whatsnew_1_0.html#api-changes), a new class [`Channel`](http://gevent.org/gevent.queue.html#gevent.queue.Channel) under the [`gevent.queue`](http://gevent.org/gevent.queue.html) module is mentioned:

> Queue(0) is now equivalent to an unbound queue and raises DeprecationError. Use gevent.queue.Channel if you need a channel.

I checked the documentation page but there is no documentation about what `Channel` is or does. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/gevent/queue.py), it appears to be similar to `Queue` but it's not a subclass of it. What exactly is the purpose or use of `Channel`? Is it a specialized queue of some sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the code for the pre-1.0 version of Gevent](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/0.13.8/gevent/queue.py#L48-L50) tells you what a `Channel` is (though I recognize this is a bit convoluted):

> `Queue(0)` is a channel, that is, its `put` method always
>   blocks until the item is delivered. (This is unlike the standard
>   `Queue`, where 0 means infinite size).

Now, as the release notes indicate, this behavior has changed in Gevent 1.0, and `Queue(0)` no longer works this way: `Channel()` does.

You'll observe that, accordingly, the implementation of `Channel.put` is significantly more complex than that of `Queue.put`.

Note that "standard `Queue`" refers to [the standard library Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).